# Audiotrack stops sound randomly, but state is STATE_INITIALIZED and PLAYSTATE_PLAYING

Tags: android, loops, audiotrack

I'm looping and audiotrack with...

```
audioTrack.setLoopPoints(0, length, -1);
audioTrack.play();
```

But after random time (several minutes), it stop sounding, but state is STATE_INITIALIZED and PLAYSTATE_PLAYING.
In that moment, I get this message ...

```
09-20 19:32:27.989: D/audio_hw_primary(176): out_standby: enter: usecase(1: low-latency_playback)
09-20 19:32:28.039: D/audio_hw_primary(176): stop_output_stream: enter: usecase(1: low-    latency-playback)
09-20 19:32:28.049: D/audio_hw_primary(176): disable_audio_route: reset mixer path: low-latency-playback
09-20 19:32:28.049: D/audio_hw_primary(176): disable_snd_device: snd_device(2: speaker)
09-20 19:32:28.049: D/audio_hw_primary(176): stop_output_stream: exit: status(0)
09-20 19:32:28.049: D/audio_hw_primary(176): out_standby: exit
```

I need to loop audiotrack limitless, please, anyone knows how to solve it ?

PD: The stop seems to happen only in versions 4.1 and later.

Comment: Do you have more of the logcat output? And on which device(s) is this? Some audio hw implementations might put outputs in standby e.g. if writing to the output device failed, or if a voice call is starting (doesn't have to be an actual call; it could happen if some app uses the `AudioManager` `setMode` function).

Comment: No, I only get that message. How can avoid another app to use AudioManager function ? Or how can I know what app  uses it ?

Comment: Oh A few seconds before appeared this message ... 09-20 03:51:18.695: W/AudioTrackShared(176): framesReady() could not lock cblk

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the phone is entering stand by, when you configured your MediaPlayer, did you get a wakelock?

```
yourMediaPlayer.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(), PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
```

Don't forget to release your mplayer later.